# How can I use a non-Angular link to navigate in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have a non-Angular component in my Angular application in which I can create a link. I would like that link to perform a page navigation in Angular without doing a full-page reload. Is this possible?

Can I call `navigateByUrl` from outside of Angular or is there another method to navigate from outside Angular (like using url fragments in Angular 1)?

Comment: lets say u have /home page where you have non-angular component and u want navigate to /otherUrl or what? please clarify your question

Comment: @PetrAveryanov, yes that's basically it. /home is a route in Angular, but the page contains a non-Angular component. I want to go to a specific route in Angular, but I don't want to reload the whole application to do it.

Answer (score 0):

**Basic**

Lets first consider usual mouse click:

```
elem.addEventListener('click', () => {
   doAngularNavigation(url);
   return false; // preventing default browser navigation
});
```

to implement `doAngularNavigation` you can use e.g. custom event

```
function doAngularNavigation(url) {
  const event = new CustomEvent("my-navigation", { url });
  window.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

and in angular app u catch this custom event and run `router.navigateByUrl`

**Advanced**

You need to mimic `router-link` directive -- there is some additional code taking into account ctrl+click, shift+click etc. https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/router/src/directives/router_link.ts